# Preventing Remote Desktop from reconnecting to lost connections after waking

Tags: macos, windows, sleep-wake, remote-desktop

Throughout a given work day, I alternate between my Windows 7 desktop and MacBook Air, using my PC via Microsoft Remote Desktop on my Mac. When I swap from my Mac to my PC, I simply close my Mac's lid and log back in at my PC, ending the Remote Desktop session.

The problem is, when I log back into my Mac, Remote Desktop reconnects automatically, logging out at the PC.

Normally this would merely an inconvenience but lately I've noticed a few key programs crashing as the result of switching between single and dual displays (I have to first minimize them on my PC prior to switching to my Mac). Plus, I've had the desktop service irrecoverably crash and been forced to hard reboot.

Prior to buying my Mac, I used a Windows laptop. Whenever the laptop was put to sleep and the RDC connection lost, upon waking Remote Desktop would simply display the connection dialog.

**Is there a way to prevent Microsoft Remote Desktop on my Mac from automatically reinitializing lost RDC connections?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

You can edit the connection and under the login settings you can untick the `Reconnect automatically if disconnected` box. You can configure this in the `Default.rdp` file or alternatively in each connection if you save separate rdp files. However, as far as I am aware it will only worked if you have saved settings for that particular machine/server.

[image: Remote Desktop Reconnect Setting]